# Save credentials for websites running on https without valid certificate

Tags: google-chrome

I often log in to my webpage that uses https protocol but that does not have a valid certificate (it is just a development site that nobody can access). Chrome 37+ does not employ autocomplete feature for log in forms in this case. (It worked before just fine.)

Can I add an exception to Chrome to tell it that it should allow autocomplete feature for that site?

Answer (score 2):

I searched through the [policy settings](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3) list, which would be the place to look for (it contains some settings used on corporate networks), and it doesn't have any such configuration, so I'm pretty sure the answer is no.

But, even though it's "just a development site", chances are you're entering the same password to it as the regular ones, so perhaps it should have the same level of security? For personal use, StartSSL provides certificates for free. On a large internal network, make your own CA certificate, configure the OS to trust it, and use it to sign local websites.

Comment: `But, even though it's "just a development site", chances are you're entering the same password to it as the regular ones` - no, I use always password 123456 for my development versions and a strong password for production versions. :) Thank you for the answer.